# How to view Adobe Flash Usage for all users?

Tags: logging, flash

How can I view which users have utilised Adobe Flash on a Windows server?  This includes through a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor application usage through the use of AppLocker.  Turn on whitelisting, but don't list the application you wish to monitor.  Also, turn AppLocker to audit only, else it will prevent access.

After this, each time a user accesses the application that AppLocker is preventing, a log entry will be input to Event Viewer, go to "Applications and Services" > "Microsoft" > "Windows" > "AppLocker" > "EXE and DLL".